# Get Maximum call stack size exceeded error while creating data in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to build simple mobile application using React Native and Firebase.
I create user info in firebase authentication table and also add some custom data to firebase real time database.

Here is my approach.

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userInfo.Email, userInfo.Password)
  .then((value) => {
    set(ref(database, "users/"), {
      userEmail: userInfo.Email,
    })
      .then((value) => console.log("d"))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

But when I run this code, I get the below error.

```
Unhandled promise rejection RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at new Promise (index.cjs:1:40657)
at Promise.then (index.cjs:1:41799)
at core.js:84:9
at new Promise (index.cjs:1:40594)
at safeThen (core.js:82:10)
at Promise.then (core.js:74:12)
at index.cjs:1:41836
at new Promise (index.cjs:1:40594)
at Promise.then (index.cjs:1:41799)
at core.js:84:9
```

Data is stored correctly but I really hate this error.
Please help me.

Comment: i believe the bootloop is happening in the component please provide a minimal or full code reproducible example

Comment: Hi Frank.
Thanks for your comment.
https://github.com/BranchDev110/Branch-Chat
Here is my full code.
Thanks in advance.

You can find the error code in screen/signUpScreen.js
Look forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: interesting this problem is quite easy to solve but you don't provide full log in devtools can i use teamviewer to observe error on devtools

Comment: Hi @TachibanaShin Thanks for your work.
Can you connect to me through steven.fredericks.dev110@gmail.com?

Comment: do you use discord? give me your uid

Comment: Thank you @TachibanaShin.
1075933426680598558